# Filter to get object based on an index and one of it's keys in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to working with Ruby. I am trying to get the first inner object (are they called Hashes in Ruby?) of an array called `numerical_answers` if one of the objects has a property of `CustomerSatisfactionAnswer`. See data below:

```
{
              :rethink_id => "123",
                      :id => 102,
             :campaign_id => 11,
              :created_at => 2021-03-25 18:14:25 -0400,
              :updated_at => 2021-03-25 18:14:31 -0400,
                  :status => 1,
       :numerical_answers => [
    [0] {
                "id" => 103,
            "number" => 2,
              "type" => "CustomerSatisfactionAnswer"
    },
    [1] {
                "id" => 104,
            "number" => 7,
              "type" => "MultipleChoice"
    }

  ],
                :language => "en",
}
```

See under `numerical_answers` there is one item in the array `[0]` and it has a `type` of `CustomerSatisfactionAnswer`. I need to be able to grab the value for `number`, but only if there is an object with that type. And it can be the first matching one in the array. Other matches don't matter. So I feel like I need to be doing some looping on `numerical_answers` until I find one that matches. But Ruby still confuses me! Help!

Comment: can you be more clear, what exactly you want to fetch from above hash ?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused myself. Basically we have a table called `responses` and inside of that we have individual survey responses like the one in the code example. What we want to know about is the first `CustomerSatisfactionAnswer` in each individual survey response. In this case, that is a `2`. So I'm trying to filter down this entire object to simply the `2` if we have that `CustomerSatisfactionAnswer` type defined. Maybe something like this?
`completed.avg { |doc| doc[:numerical_answers][:type='CustomerSatisfactionAnswer'][:number] }`

Comment: Take matching_one[:number] from my answer, you will get the result 2. I am updating my answer check once.

Comment: I'm trying to run this from the rails console without much success. Here is what I'm putting in there:
`survey = Survey.find(9)`
`results = Rethink::Response.where(:survey_id => survey.id)`
`matching_one = results.where { |doc| doc[:numerical_answers].find {|item| item["type"] == "CustomerSatisfactionAnswer"} }`
When I run `matching_one[:number]` I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'find' for var_74[:numerical_answers]:RethinkDB::RQL from (pry):156:in 'block in <main>`

Comment: I don't know why you are using Rethink, but if you want to find the element from database you can user survey.numerical_answers, I thought you are using hash / json object so suggested variable[:numerical_answers] this format. If you are operating with active record you can get the value from this format survey.numerical_answers. If you still can't get the answer, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being confusing. We use Rethink because the responses can be in the tens of thousands of rows so we store the data in Rethink and don't use Active Record.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the array of 'numerical_answers' by using following statement

```
  variable[:numerical_answers]
```

If you want to find the matching type to "CustomerSatisfactionAnswer" in the above array use following code

```
  matching_one = variable[:numerical_answers].find {|item| item["type"] == "CustomerSatisfactionAnswer"}
```

Note: In the above code 'variable' means your specified hash

So now matching_one contains

```
  {
     "id" => 103,
     "number" => 2,
     "type" => "CustomerSatisfactionAnswer"
 }
```

To get the number from the above hash, use the following code

```
  matching_one[:number]
```